# Inappsettingskit title for multivalue

Tags: ios, iphone, inappsettingskit

I am using inAppSettingsKit , I have noticed that the font size for multi select differs from the rest of the fields. Notice the Level in the picture below. I am using StoryBoards

Firstly is this intentional ?

If yes: what is the reasoning behind it ?

If not: What is the easiest way to fix it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the Issue. I cannot say I understand it but I resolved it.

I was using StoryBoards and in the Table View I had set the style to plain rather than grouped. Setting it to grouped fixed it.

Thanks to Ortwin Gentz for pointing me in the right direction.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have seen this right away - the UI clearly looks like a plain TableView.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in your app. Did you perhaps configure some special UIAppearance styles?

Or can you reproduce this in the sample app?

Comment: I will try in the sample app, I did not add any UIAppearance Styles

Comment: You are correct in that it is something that I cannot reproduce. I do not know what is causing it though